# Add text to TextView programmatically in Android Studio

Tags: android, textview

I wanted to add text in TextView programmatically. Instead of using`textView.setText("Sorry")` I want to add the word "Sorry" to the TextView.

Comment: How do you want to do so?

Comment: I want to add text "Sorry" by using a For loop so that the Sorry will be printed as much time as as the user has entered.

Comment: You mean in loop you want to set S then o then r then r then y?

Comment: When you say you want to add the text, do you mean you want to append it to the existing text?

Comment: How are you getting the user input? Do you want to update the text view once, or every time the user enters "Sorry"?

Comment: @AlkaSatvara I think you'd better provide some of your codes including the for loop.

Comment: Please provide some sample code and the expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try below code:

```
textView.append(" Sorry");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a StringBuilder for performance if numberOfTimesUserEnteredSorry is large.

```
StringBuilder sorryBuilder = new StringBuilder(textView.getText());
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimesUserEnteredSorry - 1; i++) {
    sorryBuilder.append("Sorry\n");
}

sorryBuilder.append("Sorry");

textView.setText(sorryBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++) {
    textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + " Sorry");
}
```

This will add "Sorry" to `textView` 5 times.

Comment: That will add it 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

Create an EditText, which takes input of a number(say x) from the user. Then use that to display your word x times. 
In the answer by @ohhThatVarun concatenate within setText shows error/warning. 
Try the following code:

```
    EditText et=findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView tv= findViewById(R.id.textView);

    int a= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString().trim());
    tv.setText("");
    for (int i=0;i<a;i++){
        String temp= tv.getText().toString();
        temp+=" Sorry";
        tv.setText( temp);
    }
```